# character encoding, dplyr with database (postgresql)

Tags: database, encoding, shiny, dplyr, r-dbi

I've read the threads and package updates for encoding issues with Shiny, but I have a (difficult-to-reproduce example) database-driven Shiny app which is fumbling some special characters.

In my postgresql database I see correctly my Swedish river, **"Upper Umeälven River"**, which - when I filter it back to the Shiny interface with dplyr:
`names.rivers <- filter(tbl.rivers, Country == "Sweden")`

...becomes **"Upper UmeÃ¤lven River"** in R.

I'm using UTF-8 encoding locally; I guess I'm losing something on the exchange with the database.

`Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252"`

Apologies again for the lack of example, it's ONLY an issue pulling from the database. I suspect I'm missing a flag on some sanitizing function someplace, but need some help getting pointed the right direction.

Comment: You are connecting to the DB with `dplyr`?

Comment: Hi @Carl, yes, connecting and filtering with dplyr per https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html.

Comment: Does the issue only appear with `shiny` or do you see the problem anytime you query the DB with `dplyr`

Comment: Just tested with both ```library(RPostgreSQL)``` and  ```library(DBI)``` and I get the same result -- not just in ```shiny```, but R @Carl. So it's not a ```dplyr``` issue in fact. I still can't seem to find the encoding declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, the answer was simple:
`iconv(vector.to.convert, "UTF-8")`

My "learnings":

1. Encodings of the source file, the database, and data streams are not the same thing;
2. I spent time making sure the data sources had been created in the correct encoding, ignoring the (implicit?) conversion of the datastream;
3. This page helped: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html

My understanding is a bit shallow, but - frankly - I'm not digging deeper into the world of character encoding for the moment. I hope it helps someone else avoid the error!

Comment: Hey @Jeff, I'm hoping you've dug your way deeper into the world of character encoding. I'm in exactly the same situation, and `iconv()` solves the issues as well. But I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, your answer is not completely self explanatory. Running `iconv()` on every column does not seem like the most elegant solution, so I'm looking for a way to solve the general issue.

Comment: Hi @Ratnanil - for our case the iconv() populates just one control, and on a (relatively) small resultset (generally fewer than 100 values); it's been a while, but I didn't remember digging deeper.

You're pushing postgresql queries to R? There have so many changes in R vis databases, to be honest I assumed this was an internationalization bug, and I'm surprised it's still cropping up. Have you verified it shows up with other libraries?

Comment: No I haven't tested it with other libraries yet, I'll try that when I get the time. I wrote a quick function with runs `iconv` on all columns in a `data.frame`. This makes the workflow somewhat acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In your [code page 1252 Windows Latin 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx) the rendering for the 'ä' in `Upper Umeälven River` is to the code point 0xE4 (binary 11100100).

The `Upper UmeÃ¤lven River` in the same code page has the two octets 0xC3A4 (XXX00011 XX100100).

However, if you consider the [UTF-8 encoding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History) of the code point, the significant bits are exactly the same.

Somewhere there is an inadvertent, or erroneous, character encoding taking place that transposes the character into UTF-8, but still considers the string to have the Windows Latin 1 code page.

**Perhaps the data is already being received in UTF-8** and you can change the code page to receiving code page to reflect that. There may be a silent transformation happening somewhere further back, and no indication of this.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka for the links -- after a brief panic (I read postgresql installations used to default to latin-1 encoding) I found that, at least in 9.4/9.5, I lucked out: ```ENCODING = 'UTF8'```

Comment: (For anyone following along, in pgAdmin, the SQL panel shows the data definition language to DROP or CREATE, which includes the encoding spec.).

So, I won't spend the day rebuilding a DB! However I'm not much closer to cleaning up my interface. Beginning to feel like I'm missing something simple.